# Getting React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child error

Tags: react-native

I was searching for a good boilerplate and stumbled upon this one:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/formidable-react-native-app-boilerplate

I noticed it's outdated so I am trying to fix it and get it up to date (if there is a better up to date one that would also answer my question)

Anyway I got the error in the title and in the console it says this:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children`type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
in Provider (created by Root)
in Root
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
```

And this is my root:

```
/* @flow */

import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../store/configure-store";
import Scene from "../components/scene";

const store = configureStore();

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {() => <Scene />}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

What could be the problem? I checked for TouchableHighlights with 2 elements but couldn't find it anywhere.

UPDATE:

Scene component:

```
/* @flow */
/*eslint-disable prefer-const */

import React from "react";
import App from "../containers/app";
import NavigationBar from "./navigation-bar";

let {
  Navigator,
  View
} = React;

class Scene extends React.Component {
  renderScene(route: Object, navigator: Object) {
    const Component = route.component;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <NavigationBar
          backgroundStyle={{backgroundColor: "#eee"}}
          navigator={navigator}
          route={route}
          title={route.title}
          titleColor="#333"
        />
        <Component
          navigator={navigator}
          route={route}
          {...route.passProps}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={{flex: 1}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{
          component: App,
          title: "Starter App"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Scene;
```

Comment: can you provide whats inside your <Scene>

Comment: What's the reasoning for doing this? `{() => <Scene />}`, you can just have ```<Scene />``` and it would return the component. I would also double check what's inside of the Scene component as well. Look out for those imports and I think we can give you a better answer if we can see what the Scene component looks like.

Comment: I updated my question with the scene component. The reason I had it like that is because I just downloaded the repo that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass function `{() => <Scene />}`? Shouldn't you just pass `<Scene />` component?

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Scene />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct solution but I solved it by using this repo instead:

https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux